# How to bind CollectionView SelectedItems to a List?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a CollectionView and which consists of a list of items. I can't figure out a way to bind the multiple selected items to a list in the ViewModel.

XAML Code:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" SelectedItems="{Binding NamesSelection}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
         </DataTemplate>
     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Nonfunctional ViewModel Code:

```
public MvxObservableCollection<Name> Names { get; } = new MvxObservableCollection<Name>(NamesHelpers.GetObjects());
private MvxObservableCollection<Name> _namesSelection;
public MvxObservableCollection<Name> NamesSelection 
{ 
    get=> _namesSelection;
    set 
    {
         SetProperty(ref _namesSelection, value);
    } 
}
```

This would probably work if I had a SelectedItem clause. But I'm not sure how to get it working for SelectedItems.

Ideal output would be for the NamesSelection List to populate/depopulate based on the selected items.

Comment: are `Names` and `NamesSelection` the same type?  I would expect that to work, apart from the obvious problem (type mismatch) in your VM

Comment: also `_namesSelection` is not the same type of `NamesSelection`, so `get=> _namesSelection;` would throw an error

Comment: Sorry, that was an typo. _namesSelection and NamesSelection are of the same type. But Names is of type MvxObservableCollection

Comment: and what's the type of the `MvxObservableCollection<X>`?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais it's the same as NamesSelection

Comment: your `NamesSelection` needs to be `MvxObservableCollection<string>`, **OR**  `Names` need to be `List<string>`, they need to be the same, my guess is that you need to change `Names` to `List<string>` CollectionView may not recognize MvxObservableCollection from MVVMCross, keep it simple and use `List<>` or `ObservableCollection<>`

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 3):

`SelectedItems` must be an `IList<object>`.  `ObservableCollection<object>` does not implement that interface *(nor does eg. `List<Name>`, due to covariance)*, so that will not work.

The workaround is to bind `SelectedItems` to a `List<object>`, then subscribe to the `SelectionChanged` event.  Then manually update the bindings when the selected items change.

Comment: ObservableCollection<object> does implement IList<object>, as the T carries over to the base. However, ObservableCollection<Name> does not implement IList<object>. Using ObserbableCollection<object> will solve the problem.

Comment: I could not get SelectedItems to change either until I declared it with <object>.  Then in SelectionChangedCommand the IList bound to SelectedItems is cast to the actual list type.

Comment: Thank you for these comments.  I spent a few hours trying to get my SelectItems to populate from the CollectionView and could not figure out why it didn't work.  You literally have to use ObservableCollection<object> and IList<object> and it must be figuring out what "object" refers to by the ItemSource binding. Ugh... the MS documentation page for CollectionViews does mention using <object> for the selected items list, but for some reason I assumed I was supposed to substitute my class name in for "object".

Answer (score 0):

Try having NamesSelection as ObservableCollection
or same as Names => MvxObservableCollection
Check here
[Multi Pre-Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#multiple-pre-selection)

Comment: Please share ViewModel having Names and NamesSelection

Comment: Updated the question with proper types of objects

Comment: Please check you are initializing and assigning NamesSelection properly (in constructor or the place same as done for Names).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#multiple-selection

Comment: no, I switched to using CheckBox within a StackLayout

Answer (score 0):

`NamesSelection`(*List*) and `Names`(*MvxObservableCollection*) need to be the same collection type, so either do:

```
private MvxObservableCollection<string> _namesSelection;
public MvxObservableCollection<string> NamesSelection
{ 
    get=> _namesSelection;
    set 
    {
        SetProperty(ref _namesSelection, value);
    } 
}
```

Or

```
List<string> Names { get; }
```

In my opinion, I recommend using `List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>`, since they are the most common types of collection objects, `MvxObservableCollection` may not be supported by `CollectionView` or can cause some issues

Comment: I updated all of them to be MvxObservalbleCollection , still doesn't work

Comment: @S.Patole try using List or ObservableCollection Instead, and what do you receive on [SelectionChangedCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection) event?

Comment: Changing all of it to List<T> didn't change anything

Comment: @S.Patole what do you mean by "didn't change anything"? is NamesSelection empty? null? or it's not reflected on the screen?

Comment: I can see the Names on the screen and even select them but NamesSelection SetProperty never gets hit.

Comment: why would the setter of a collection be hit when an item is added?

Comment: @S.Patole the SetProperty is only hitted when a collection is **changed**, changing the items of a collection will not trigger it, since the collection remains the same.

Comment: @S.Patole if you want to "debug" whether or not NamesSelection is being filled with the selected items, use SelectionChangedCommand and see if it's hit after selecting an item, or create a temporary button with a click event/command, put a breakpoint in it, select some items, and then press that button and see if the collection has some items

Comment: Never used MvxCross, but don't you need to define the Mode as TwoWay for changes to go from view to VM and VM to view?

Comment: @SomeStudent that's actually a good point, default [TwoWay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#two-way-bindings) properties does not include CollectionView SelectedItems, but that list doesn't seemed to be updated either, just to be sure, @S.Patole can use `{Binding NamesSelection, Mode=TwoWay}`